# Latest ROS doesn't install due to broken packages on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ros, ubuntu-oneiric, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting an error that there are broken packages when I try to install ROS on Ubuntu 11.10.  What should I do?  I followed all the directions and then it pulled out an error after I did the rosinstall command.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31415/latest-ros-doesn%27t-install-due-to-broken-packages-on-ubuntu-11.10/) by [shyamalschandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/2087/shyamalschandra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-04-07

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-04-07**:
Could you please clarify? Are you trying to build Fuerte from source, or Electric using the Ubuntu package manager? If it's the former, please post your errors. If it's the latter, have you checked these instructions (http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu) out?

**Comment by [shyamalschandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/2087/shyamalschandra/) on 2012-04-07**:
Yes, those are the instructions that I used to install Electric on Ubuntu 11.10.  I am unsure about what to do.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-07**:
Please include more information, and include the actual errors you are seeing. http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please try again after running "sudo apt-get update".  You may have gotten an inconsistent view.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1